# Failing to install py2neo on CentOS

Tags: python, centos, py2neo

I am trying to install py2neo on a CentOS server. It fails with the following message:

```
File "setup.py", line 29, in <module>
from py2neo import __author__, __email__, __license__, __package__, __version__
File "/root/Downloads/py2neo-2.0/py2neo/__init__.py", line 27, in <module>
from py2neo.core import *
File "/root/Downloads/py2neo-2.0/py2neo/core.py", line 1313
new_inst.__stale.update({"labels", "properties"})
                                 ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

This happens whether I am using `pip install py2neo` or I install manually after downloaded the module.
When I try the same command on a MacBook everything goes well.

Can  someone assist me?

Comment: Hi there @patrick - unfortunately you seem to have landed on the wrong site :( [so] is for programming related questions  where your post is more closely related to administration of a server. Perhaps [su] or [sf] would be better suited to your question.

Comment: What version of CentOS are you using? This sounds like a python version mismatch (the installed version is older than what `py2neo` supports). That appears to be python 2.7 syntax, I think.

Answer (score 1):

You're probably trying to install under Python 2.6, which doesn't support the literal `set` syntax and so is expecting a `dict` instead.

As Etan mentions above, py2neo does not support Python 2.6. You'll have to upgrade to either Python 2.7 or Python 3.

Comment: Thank you Nigel, This solved my problem. I successfully managed to install py2neo after upgrading my version of python to 2.7